# How to achieve this effect on :focus

Tags: html, css, focus, border

I saw this on a website:

[image]

Then, when you click in it...
[image]

How would you recreate this? Not just a plain solid border, but like that one. I scanned through the source code but couldn't find anything. Not in the css, or the javascript.

The site I got this from is:
http://www.minecraft-schematics.com/search/

I'm pretty sure this would be a `:focus` effect, but I couldn't find it in the source code, as I said...

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried css shadows?

Comment: I knew this would get downvotes, but I really had to know...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the source of that particular element on the page you refer to:

```
input[type="text"]:focus {
    border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    outline: 0;
    outline: thin dotted 9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}
```

*I got this through Chrome by forcing the element into focus-state and then inspecting the applied CSS-rules. In Chrome Devtools you can right-click on any DOM-element in the inspector and then choose "Force element state" -> ":focus"*

**Side note:** From the looks of it, that page is built on the popular UI-framework [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's part of bootstrap.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/nBEqA/3/)

```
.fancy {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -webkit-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
    -moz-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
    -o-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
    transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.fancy:focus {
    border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    outline: 0;
    outline: thin dotted 9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The text box is using a [CSS3 `box-shadow`](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/):. The CSS below will put the shadow effect on all text boxes on focus:

```
input[type^="text"] {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #0077cc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: .2em;
    outline: none; /*Stops Chrome putting a yellow border on the textbox*/
}
input[type^="text"]:focus {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #0077cc;
}
```